# How do calculate / determine the reference voltage for the error amplifier of my analog PWM generator for a 0-100% duty cycle

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, class-b-amplifier

For a school project I am building an analog PWM generator with 0.1 to full-scale linearity and a duty cycle 0-100%. Powersupply is 5 Volt and 100% is equal to 5V at the output. The frequency 1 Khz.

My circuit is done for like 80%. The problem I have is with the reference voltage of my error amplifier. My research so far has shown that this gives you the ability to have the 0-100% duty cycle.

When I apply a reference of 2.5 Volt, I see that my dutycycle is 50%. When I change Vin to change the duty cycle , it changes with 0.5V to 0% or 100% from reference voltage.

So, 
2V = 0%

2,5V = 50%

3V = 100%

Sidenote:

I used the slau508 design and theory, but my design differs slighty because mine is not going to be used for audio, hence why I need to adjust the reference voltage according to my teacher.

How can I fix this so that I can change the dutycycle from 0 to 100%?

I need to have a reference voltage for my error amplifier so that I can have a duty cycle from 0-100% with a voltage change of Vin from 0-5V.

With the reference of 2,5V that I have right now I can only go from 0 to 100 procent with an increase or decrease of 0,5V. This should be 5V in order to change between 0 and 100% dutycycle.

My question is:

How can I calculate or determine what I have to do with the reference voltage in order to have the 0-100% duty cycle with a voltage change of Vin from 0-5V?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what help you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry , i thought i was clear. i need to have a reference voltage for my error amplifier so that i can have an duty cycle from 0-100%. with the reference of 2,5V  that i have right now i can only go from 0 to 100 procent with an increase or decrease of 0,5V. This should be 5V in order to change between 0 and 100% dutycycle.       my question, is how can calculate or determine what i have to do with the reference voltage in order to have th 0-100% duty cylce with a voltage change of Vin from 0-5V?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently with R3 at 10k you get +/-50% duty cycle changes for +/- 0.5 volts centred on 2.5 volts. You want this to be +/- 2.5 volts so, make R3 five times bigger at 50 kohm.

Comment: What has R3 to do with the reference voltage?  If you make R3 bigger the frequency of my integrator will change from 53 Hz to (still have to calculate). Making R3 will have the capacitor charge more slowly due the fact that there is less current, referring to Ohms law?

Comment: C1 and R4 integrate out the PWM and create "analogue" negative feedback. I said adjust R3. Why not try it or simulate it because I'm not going to get into a long discussion about this.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why you give me that advice. I dont have the packages or components in my simulation tool.

Comment: Increasing R3 lowers the gain and hence you require more volts at the input for the same duty cycle.

Comment: Okéy,  im going to try that. Also i'm checking if I can find op amp models that I can download for lt Spice to simulatie . Thnx for the advice.

Comment: You should be able to use virtually any op-amp model (especially if you give the op-amp a bit of negative supply voltage (in case you can't find a rail-to-rail type.

Comment: Thanks , that really helps. I could not find any and started to watch video's how to make your own component

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  It worked,  altough 50kohm is not the proper recistance to have an 0-100% duty cycle. It comes really close. With the 50kohm how fast he can pwm seems to be slower than before. Im going to calculate what the frequency of the error amplifier is.

Comment: It won't be exact because resistors have tolerances, op-amps have offset voltages and the reference won't be precisely half the supply rail. Neither will the comparators hit exactly top and bottom of their power rails when producing a square wave. These all cause errors. The error amp doesn't have a frequency - the triangle wave generator sets the frequency of PWM.

Comment: BTW did you feed the 2.5V reference voltage directly to the non-inverting input of the error amplifier - I think this is the difference you mentioned in the question. Also did you use a smaller value than the 8k45 (R5)?

Comment: Yes I have a reference of 2.5 v at that pin. Now a have an recistance of 57,5 ohm and I can change my duty cycle from 0 -100% . Thanks

Comment: OK, cool, please consider accepting the answer formally but maybe wait another day in case anyone else wants to chip in with some fine observations.